# Can't make Bootstrap tooltip work in a page that also uses jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

js import sequence

```
jQuery.js  ( 1.9.1)
jQuery UI  (1.10)
Bootstrap.js  (3.2)
```

calling this at the bottom of the page:

```
$(document.body).tooltip({ selector: "[title]", placement: 'right' });
```

Tooltip comes up but it is jQuery tooltip (I know because I am using a distinctive jQuery UI theme).

If I remove jQuery UI import, the tooltip turns into plain default HTML/browser tooltip.
Why isn't bootstrap tooltip code loading?

Comment: can you please share jsfiddle of it.

Comment: If you don't have any other use for jQuery UI, remove it and use bootstrap tool tip on the element directly. E.g. `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>`

Comment: thanks. this fiddle thing helped.  apparently there was a conflict.  Downloaded latest Bootstrap and it worked.

Comment: Please self-answer your question. Otherwise it is likely to stay marked as 'unanswered'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved after downloading the latest versions of bootstrap.  One thing I needed to do though.  I put these lines after including both jQuery UI and Bootstrap javascript files (in that sequence).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var btn = $.fn.button.noConflict() // reverts $.fn.button to jqueryui btn
$.fn.btn = btn // assigns bootstrap button functionality to $.fn.btn
</script>
```

Without this,  .buttonset() function of jQuery UI was not working, consequently, those button type fancy option options were not showing up on pages.  With this case, buttons from jQuery and Tooltip from Bootstrap are working.  Thank you everybody.